# Text process filter IP addressees that appear in log too frequently and add them to deny list

Tags: text-processing

I am attempting to extract any IP address from nginx that loads my websites page more than 10 times within a 60 second window but it must be for the homepage only `GET / HTTP` part of the nginx log `/var/log/nginx/access.log` then convert those IPs into a deny list `/etc/nginx/conf.d/includes-optional/deny.conf`

```
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31822 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31826 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31826 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31714 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31822 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31794 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31774 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31748 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31774 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31720 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31820 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
2.2.2.2 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31834 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31822 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31826 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31826 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31714 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31822 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31794 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31774 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31748 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31774 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31720 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31820 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
1.1.1.1 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:02:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31834 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/18B92 Safari/604.1 Puffin/8.0.2LP"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
3.3.3.3 - - [06/Sep/2021:21:13:36 +0200] "GET /image.php?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_7 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/175.0.393249130 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

As both of these IPs appear more than 10 times and are in the root `/` directory when the command runs the following should be added to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/includes-optional/deny.conf`

```
deny 1.1.1.1;
deny 2.2.2.2;
```

This also has to work with IPv6 addresses

Comment: why not just use `nginx`'s [limit_req](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) rate-limiting module?

Comment: Causes problems with other pages that load lots of images. Half the images don't load

Comment: This sounds like you're reimplementing `fail2ban`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tiny project in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) to do this kind of thing, named [`txrban`](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txrban/tree/). I've been running this for years. It's unfortunately undocumented.

The programs `apache.txr`, `exim.txr` and `ssh.txr` are the entry points into it. These programs scan the web server logs, mail server logs and the `auth.log` for SSH activity. You can clone one of these programs, most likely `apache.txr` and tweak it to do what you want.

These programs load the `txrban.txr` main module, which also loads `utils.txr` and a `config.txr`. The `config.txr` doesn't exist in the git repo; only a sample version that has to be renamed and edited.

The `startup.sh` script is what I use to start the three processes on bootup. The programs daemonize themselves via the `daemon` function in TXR Lisp and use `syslog` for reporting banning and unbanning events.

There is no persistence of the banned adresses; that's just kept in a hash table in memory. (Patches welcome.) On startup, the program reads the existing logs and performs all the implied banning and unbanning (which can take a bit of time), then switches to real-time mode: tailing the logs and reacting to new material.

In the `config.txr` file, there are various parameters.

The `*ban-duration*` is used for points-based banning. The log-scanning points can report an IP address along with a nonzero score. The address is immediately banned for a duration of time which is determined by using the score as an index into this `*ban-duration*` list.

The parameters `*short-period*`, `*short-limit*` and `*short-ban*`, and their `long` counterparts, determine time-based banning. The period is the access period of interest, and the limit is the maximum number of accesses in that period. The `ban` value is the duration of the ban.  If an IP address' access pattern violates the long ban parameter, then it is subject to the long ban. Otherwise if it violates the short ban then it is banned accordingly.

The main programs just have to scan logs and report interesting events by calling the `report` function, with three arguments: IP address, time and points.   (There is an optional fourth parameter used by the SSH module to report the user ID being attempted from the given IP address. The SSH module penalizes IP addresses which are trying failed logins using multiple user IDs.)

Comment: Take a look at `fail2ban` :)

Comment: @roaima I did at the time I started that project. It was too complicated to get it working, so I gave up.  The problem doesn't require more than a few hundred lines of scripting.

Comment: sorry to hear you found it too complicated. I reckon spent about four hours in total setting it up. A couple working out what it didn't already do, and then probably 4x 30 minutes over the subsequent week or so tweaking the timers. I've since applied that to two other unrelated systems

Comment: @roaima I don't think I spent that much time developing txrban. I made the right decision. I think OP could easily tweak it to work like he or she wants.